# Get the size of image in a tmp folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I was wondering how I can get the size of a file that's been saved to a temp folder. I am using carrierwave to upload my images and if validation fails a thumbnail of the image is shown within the form

```
<% if build.object.image? %>
  <%= image_tag build.object.image_url :small_animal_image %>
  <%= build.hidden_field :image_cache %> 
<% end %>
```

From what I have read, this is normal behavior.

I would like to get the file size of the original image uploaded but using the **size** method I only get a 0 returned

```
def example_method
image = params[:animal][:animal_images_attributes]

image.each do |k,v|
img_cache = v["image_cache"]
img_cache_size = img_cache.size
img = v["image"]

  ap(img_cache)
  ap(img)
  ap(img_cache_size)

 end
end
```

The output of the above in the console is

```
"0"
""
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000002fe40c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140926-3003-1rfzkcq>, @original_filename="cat.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"animal[animal_images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"cat.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
0
```

This is what the hash looks like

```
animal_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image_cache"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000002fe40c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140926-3003-1rfzkcq>, @original_filename="cat.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"animal[animal_images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"cat.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this :

```
tempfilepath = params[:animal][:animal_images_attributes][:image].tempfile.path
size = `identify #{tempfilepath} | awk '{print $7}'`
```

make sure you have identify working in terminal.

**Update**

A more easier solution will be

```
File.size(tempfilepath)
```

Comment: thanks very much, would you mind explaining the second part to me though?

Comment: and also how would i get the size back as a number as opposed to a string? so that i can then run comparisons on it

Comment: sure, identify actually uses imagemagick to provide information about images, the second part gives is used to take out the size from the information displayed by identify which looks something like : `cuscopanorama.jpg JPEG 1000x284 1000x284+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 66KB 0.000u 0:00.000` we will get 66KB from here. If you want only the number, try using a regex method example: `"66KB".scan(/\d+/).join.to_i`

Comment: well i just done size = File.size(tempfilepath) and that seems to work :-) thanks for your help, appreciated

Comment: wwow, thanks man I will use this for myself :p thats a way better solution. I will add this too :)